# Unable to get addScriptDeclaration() to work inside a module

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have a very simple module that is loaded from a plugin via

```
<?php echo JHtml::_('content.prepare', '{loadposition mymodule}');  ?>
```

The module position is setup, and the default.php template renders the output appropriately.  What doesn't work is the following:

```
$js = <<<FOO
(function ($) {
    console.log("javascript loaded");
})(jQuery);
FOO;

$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScriptDeclaration($js);  // no js is output in HTML here?? Why?

JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_mymodule');
```

The embedded javascript is not rendered with the rest of the HTML.

Comment: Did you check the <head> tag ? that is where the js should be displayed, when you use addScriptDeclaration, not 'inline' near your module code.

Comment: Yes, I checked/searched. It's not there.  If I var_dump to an error_log the structure, it's there but never renders to the browser.

Comment: For expediency, though not what I was attempting, I just embedded directly into the default layout to just make it work.